# scala spark Redis

Tags: scala, redis

In my SampleTest application, I design the code like after receiving new search pattern from the client the `StreamingContext` should be stoped(`ssc.stop()`) and again start with the newly assigned pattern( `ssc.start()` ).

Stoping the StreamingContext (`ssc.stop()` ) is fine but, while starting the StreamingContext (`ssc.start()` ) it will through the `akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException:` sending to terminated ref breaks promises exception. I would also want to know why this exception occurs in the code.

Let me know if required any additional information regarding to this problem.

The following specified ERROR and Exception which I got.

> ERROR network.ConnectionManager: Corresponding
>   SendingConnectionManagerId not found
>
> spark.SparkException: Error sending message to BlockManager as
>   driverActor is null [message = spark.storage.UpdateBlockInfo@88140ed]
>           at spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.askDriverWithReply(BlockManagerMaster.scala:127)
>           at spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.updateBlockInfo(BlockManagerMaster.scala:56)
>           at spark.storage.BlockManager.spark$storage$BlockManager$$tryToReportBlockStatus(BlockManager.scala:247)
>           at spark.storage.BlockManager.reportBlockStatus(BlockManager.scala:217)
>           at spark.storage.BlockManager.liftedTree1$1(BlockManager.scala:560)
>           at spark.storage.BlockManager.put(BlockManager.scala:534)
>           at spark.streaming.dstream.NetworkReceiver.pushBlock(NetworkInputDStream.scala:147)
>           at spark.streaming.dstream.NetworkReceiver$BlockGenerator.spark$streaming$dstream$NetworkReceiver$BlockGenerator$$keepPushingBlocks(NetworkInputDStream.scala:251)
>           at spark.streaming.dstream.NetworkReceiver$BlockGenerator$$anon$1.run(NetworkInputDStream.scala:205)

Comment: What are you doing with Redis?